# How to find an element of an array then adding it to another array with user input?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, class, switch-statement

For a programming project we have to make a menu that manages an inventory of books to be bought and sold. One of the menu options is supposed to add a book from the store's inventory into the customer's shopping cart. The user should be able to type the title of the book then the program would search the inventory array and find the book.

Here's what I have:

```
void Customer::addBook(Customer cust, Book bookList[]) {
string choice;
int i = 0;
int gotIt = 0;
cout << "Please enter the name of the book to add to your shopping cart (case sensitive)" << endl;
cin >> choice;
while (i < 22 && gotIt == 0) {
    if (choice == bookList[i].getTitle()) {
        cust.shopCart[cust.size] = bookList[i];
        gotIt = 1;
        cust.size++;
    }
}
```

This function is being called from a switch statement. When I type in the title of the book I want to add to the cart, the program does nothing. I think their might be an issue with how I'm comparing the user entered string and the title of the book they're looking for.

Would someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Most likely, it's because you're passing the `Customer` object by value. Try changing the parameters of the `addBook` function to `Customer& cust, Book bookList[]`

Comment: Are there any spaces in the name of the book?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here.It's specially important to post a [mcve].

Comment: Aslo try checking if the book is added by adding something like a `cout<<"Book Added";` inside your `if` statement. If the programs prints that, then it's easy to figure out where the problem is

Comment: @RSahu there are spaces in the names of the books, yes.

Comment: @lilbroomstick I made the changes suggested and it didn't fix it, but it also didn't make it worse

Comment: @Braannflakes `cin` skips whitespaces, so that's where the problem is. might want to try `getline()`

Comment: @ArunAS alright, I'll try getline next . I added the cout statement right after cust.size++; and it didn't output the cout statement

Comment: @ArunAS i am now using getline(cin, choice) instead of cin >> choice and it's still not doing anything

Comment: i found another problem, you are not increasing value of `i` in your loop

Comment: @ArunAS good catch, that seems to have fixed it!